# Можно ли cделать hover не на все части div?

Tags: html, css, hover

Предположим есть такой код

```html
<div id="block_1"> 
  <div class="first">Privet1</div>
  <div class="second">Privet2</div>
</div>
<div id="block_2"> 
  <div class="first">Privet1</div>
  <div class="second">Privet2</div>
</div>
```

Можно ли как нибудь сделать hover еффект только на first, не обращаясь непосредственно вот так .first:hover

Так как таких классов .first может быть на странице много, нужно соблюдать иерархию.
Нужно что то вот такого: #block_1 .first:hover{...}

Comment: если иерархию, то `div>div:first-of-type:hover {
  ...
}`

Comment: `#block_1 .first:hover`  вот так и можно

Comment: Но оно почему то не работало  так

Answer (score 0):

Установи какой-нибудь класс всем блокам, у которых будет тот самый **.first**

```
.block > .first:hover { ... }
```